# How to force ipad to use the standard listbox used in desktop instead of the ipad version?

Tags: html, ios, css, forms, ipad

The iPad uses native controls and doesn't show all the items of the multiselect list box (unless I click on it in which case it shows a menu for making my selections). I would like to have the iPad view of this control same as the desktop view. Is there any way to force the desktop view?

```
<select id="myListBox" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="1">Option 2</option>
<option value="1">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.